# trim and trimends in powerapps not working

Tags: trim, powerapps, blank-line

i'm currently trying to validate a text field, to ensure that its not just blank spaces, using the OnChange ACTION in powerapps

both the trim(textfieldname.Text) and trimends(textfieldname.Text) functions do nothing.

The IsEmpty and IsBlank functions also seem to accept blank spaces

Does anyone have a way to validate text fields to stop the user from inputing blank spaces in powerapps?

Cheers
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Use button. Button has OnSave characteristic where you can use these functions and it will reflect accordingly while saving form(if using form). This way you can validate a string before saving. 
Also use Datacard before using plain TextField which has many functionalities.